# Fire event when browser parses/renders a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Assume that we know that an element (or a very specific selector) is going to appear on a page. Is it possible to set up beforehand, via JS or jQuery, an event that goes off when the browser gets to that element and parses it? This is NOT content loaded through AJAX but is present in the primary page's source.

The reason for this need is that I'm working with a hosted system that greatly limits where and when I can inject code to fix problems with the page. I can pretty much only place my code at the start and end of what is a really long page. Right now, the page has to load completely before it can inject any desired changes (yuck!). Plus, I cannot make the pages shorter in content.

This is basically the process I would like to happen:

```
Page begins loading
Listener set up to watch for .specialClass elements
...
.specialClass element gets parsed/added to DOM
Listener triggers function on that element
...
.specialClass element gets parsed/added to DOM
Repeat as before
...
Page finishes rendering
```

So, is this possible at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use mutation observers for that, they also get notified by the parser

Comment: Link to documentation/example? Or a plugin that automates the setup? Even better, one that includes a polyfill back to IE8 (I know... but we have legacy patrons who never upgrade).

Comment: the very first google result: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I was aware of that link already. If you happen to look at the example code, you will see that it relies upon the target existing when you call that code. Otherwise, you get a type error.